# ReactJS: try to update a value but receive error: "Maximum update depth exceeded."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to realize a way to do a sorting of data (ascending or descending).

I have this in the return to create a select:

```
return(
      <Row>
        <Search
          onSubmit={ this.handleFilter }
          onReset={ this.handleFilterReset }
          Fields={[
            {
              component: Fields.Select,
              name: 'name',
              label: 'Date',
              col: ['lg-12', 'md-12'],
              data: self.fieldSelect()
            }
          ]}
        />  

fieldSelect(){
  {
    return [
      {
        label: "Disc",
        value: this.setState({ordering: false})
      },
      {
        label: "Asc",
        value: this.setState({ordering: true})
      }   
    ]
  }
  }
```

And I would to change the value this.state.ordering that change the type of sorting

My problem is that I try to operate in this way I receive the error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

How can I do? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, it's dificult to say exactly how to solve the problem, but I can tell you how to avoid the

`Maximum update depth exceeded...`

When your component is trying to render

```
return(
...
   data: self.fieldSelect()//Calling a function
...
);
```

You are calling to `self.fieldSelect()` which is calling two times to `setState`

```
fieldSelect(){
return [
  {
    label: "Disc",
    value: this.setState({ordering: false})//first call
  },
  {
    label: "Asc",
    value: this.setState({ordering: true})//second call
  }   
 ]
}
```

with this two calls you are changing the state, meaning that the component will enter in a infinite loop.
If you are expecting to call `this.setState({ordering:true})` when one of your options is selected, you need to do it on the select `onChange` function, which in this case given your code, must be on `CustomOnChange`

Comment: The problem is that I should only change the this.state.ordering in true or false when the user choose Asc or Disc from the select

Comment: About `CustomOnChange` what did you suggest to do?

Comment: ``CustomOnChange`` should handle the value, either asc or desc, so you should call the ```setState({ordering:})``` given the value

Comment: I have tried to add in the fieldSelect() `CustomOnChange: this.setState({ordering: true})`  but the error's message is the same

Comment: assuming your fields are ```[{ label: "Disc", value: "Disc" }, { label: "Asc", value: "Asc" }]``` I think you should call as follows: ```CustomOnChange: (value) => { if (value === 'Disc') 
{ this.setState({ordering:false}) } else { this.setState(ordering:true) } }``` If you need more help, please update the code of your question with the "CustomOnChange" definition

Comment: Ok I have update my post with your implementation, I receive now a different error